# Scoping problems with comprehensions

Tags: elixir

I want to perform some analytics on a series of combinations of values.

I have the following function, but for some reason, after the comprehensions are completed and at the end of the function body, the variable `analytics` is still an empty list, while it's not inside the comprehension on each iteration

Any ideas?

```
def handle_cast({:start}, state) do
    intervals = [7, 30, 90]
    groupings = ["day_of_week", "time_of_day"]
    aggregators = [
      %{
        domain: "support",
        metric: "new_conversations",
        func:   &App.get_new_conversations/2
      },
      %{
        domain: "support",
        metric: "closed_conversations",
        func:   &App.get_closed_conversations/2
      },
      %{
        domain: "support",
        metric: "median_response_time",
        func:   &App.get_median_response_time/2
      },
    ]

    Repo.transaction(fn ->
      Repo.delete_all(Analytic)

      analytics = []
      for interval <- intervals do
        for grouping <- groupings do
          for %{domain: domain, metric: metric, func: func} <- aggregators do
            analytic =
              func.(grouping, interval)
              |> Enum.map(fn %{"app_id" => app_id, "data" => data} = result ->
                %Analytic{app_id: app_id, domain: domain, metric: metric, grouping: grouping, interval_in_days: interval, data: data}
              end)

            analytics = [analytic|analytics]
          end
        end
      end
    end)

    {:noreply, state}
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in Elixir are immutable but rebindable. What this means is that the line `analytics = [analytic|analytics]` is creating a new list and binding it to the variable named `analytics` for the scope of that block. When the block ends, the changes are not persisted in the next iteration of the `for`. For example:

```
iex(1)> x = 1
1
iex(2)> for i <- 1..3 do
...(2)>   IO.puts(x); x = x + i; IO.puts(x)
...(2)> end
1
2
1
3
1
4
```

For the code you've written, you can use the fact that `for` returns a list of the values of the last expression inside them and store the return value of the outermost `for` to `analytics`, but there's a slight problem: you'll end up with nested lists:

```
iex(1)> for i <- 1..2 do
...(1)>   for j <- 1..2 do
...(1)>     for k <- 1..2 do
...(1)>       {i, j, k}
...(1)>     end
...(1)>   end
...(1)> end
[[[{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}], [{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}]],
 [[{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}], [{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}]]]
```

But, there's a simple solution! `for` accepts multiple `<-` clauses in a single call and automatically returns a flat list:

```
iex(1)> for i <- 1..2, j <- 1..2, k <- 1..2 do
...(1)>   {i, j, k}
...(1)> end
[{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1},
 {2, 2, 2}]
```

Using this method, your code becomes:

```
analytics =
  for interval <- intervals,
      grouping <- groupings,
      %{domain: domain, metric: metric, func: func} <- aggregators do
      func.(grouping, interval)
      |> Enum.map(fn %{"app_id" => app_id, "data" => data} = result ->
        %Analytic{app_id: app_id, domain: domain, metric: metric, grouping: grouping, interval_in_days: interval, data: data}
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

This should give you the same output you were most likely expecting from the original code.